# Trying to populate a JComboBox with integer values from a database. What is wrong in the code?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jdbc, jcombobox

I am building a library management system. I have book_ID values as int in the Issue Table. How to add them to the comboBox. Each student has multiple books on his name. I want to add the comboBox to select a particular book to use in return book class.

```
 JComboBox<Integer> bookID = new JComboBox<Integer>();
            bookID.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                    ArrayList<Integer> books  = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                    String query = "SELECT Book_ID FROM Issue where Student_ID=?";
                    try {
                        pst = conn.prepareStatement(query);
                        rs = pst.executeQuery(query);
                        while(rs.next()){
                            int id = rs.getInt("Book_ID");
                            books.add(id);
                        }
                        rs.close();
                    } catch (SQLException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    // populate the combo box
                    DefaultComboBoxModel<Integer> model = new DefaultComboBoxModel<Integer>((Integer[]) books.toArray());
                    bookID.setModel(model);
                }
            });
            bookID.setBounds(467, 53, 163, 26);
            contentPane.add(bookID);
```

Comment: Don't use a `MouseListener` on a `JComboBox`, users use keyboards to. The question is, why wait until the user tries to activate the combobox before populating it?  Why not populate it once you know the student id?  Which raises the question of, when did you bind the student id to the query parameter?

Comment: I used the student_ID to populate Student Data textfields but couldn't find a way to add the Book_ID values to the comboBox during the same query. So tried this.

Comment: You never bind the "student_id" parameter. Once you've loaded the student details, I'd recommend loading the book details then

Comment: I got to the point where I add the student details like name, semester into JTextField using a Search Button. The second part of the form has the book details that will be returned. The thing is I issued multiple books for the same student_ID. This is where I am stuck. I choose to add the comboBox to select a book_ID for populating the Book Details. Now I don't know how to populate the comboBox with Integer values. This is where I need help.